# Scope and use of super keyword in Java

Tags: java, super

Why can't I access the parent class variable with the super keyword?

With the below code, the output is:

```
feline cougar c c
```

```
class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";

    public Feline() {
        System.out.print("feline ");
    }
}

public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public Cougar() {
        System.out.print("cougar ");

    }

    void go() {
        type = "c ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cougar().go();
    }
}
```

Comment: You *are* accessing the parent class variable. The one that you just set to `"c "`.

Comment: I was thinkin that he f should be accesed from class feline

Comment: There's only one variable, and it can only have one value. That value was `"f "` until you changed it to `"c "`.

Comment: @shmosel:  That's what it looks like to me.  That's what all of the other duplicates state it is, too.  I want to see a convincing argument as to what you think it is instead before you peter out and not reopen the question, though.

Comment: if I again declare as srting type = c in subclass then I am getting the f output so I am bit confused here and whants to know what actually it happning

Comment: @Makoto Hiding would imply the variable is redeclared in the subclass. It isn't.

Comment: @shmosel:  Ah.  Fair point.  I'll reopen it then.

Comment: @Makoto can u plzz expain bit more

Comment: Explain what? Why would you think a variable could hold two values simultaneously?

Comment: @PrashantChaturvedi Do you understand what inheritance means?  There isn't a second "virtual parent object" that contains its own data.

Comment: but when I am redeclaring  it as string type='c' I get the output as f at this time why it is not having the same value

Comment: Maybe you should post an example code for each scenario you are trying to describe in English.

Comment: class Feline 
{     public String type = "f ";     
public Feline() 
{         System.out.print("feline ");    
} 
} 
 public class Cougar extends Feline 
{     public Cougar() 
{         System.out.print("cougar "); 
}  
 void go() 
{    String type = "c ";                
   System.out.print( this.type + super.type);
}    
public static void main(String[] args) 
{         
    new Cougar().go();    
} 
} 
 here I get the output as feline cougar c f

Comment: That's because you now have 2 completely different variables, why would they have the same value?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the original question is simple: There is only one variable called type. Its initial value gets overwritten by c. Remember that there is only one object, so one variable. Prashant's code creates a second variable and obviously that one doesn't overwrite the original string in the parent class.